# Constructing JSON reponse with Python API

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

My issue is rather simple, but due to my inexperience I am not sure how to accomplish what I want to do.

The backend that I am utilizing is Google App Engine, but I believe this is a general python question.

**How can I structure my JSON response to return the exact object JSON back that was initially sent in the request?**

```
    class UserCreateRequestMessage(messages.Message):
    email = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
    password = messages.StringField(2, required=True)


class UserCreateResponseMessage(messages.Message):
    email = messages.StringField(1)
    username = messages.StringField(2)
    # id = messages.IntegerField(3)
```

**HERE IS THE API, THE PROBLEM IS WITH THE RETURN LINE**

```
    @endpoints.api(name='photoswap', version='v1')
class PhotoswapAPI(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(UserCreateRequestMessage, UserCreateResponseMessage,
                      path='user', http_method='POST',
                      name='user.create')
    def user_create(self, request):
        entity = User(email=request.email, password=request.password)
        entity.put()
        return UserCreateResponseMessage(email=entity.email, password=entity.password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to a message class that did not contain "password" and instead contained "username".

I fixed the issue below.

```
class UserCreateRequestMessage(messages.Message):
    email = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
    password = messages.StringField(2, required=True)


class UserCreateResponseMessage(messages.Message):
    email = messages.StringField(1)
    password = messages.StringField(2)
```